# How to show more than 10 results in eXide (eXist-db)?

Tags: exist-db, exide

I wonder how to make eXide to return more than 10 results. No matter how I query the database, it is not possible to get more. Is there some special rule in $EXIST_HOME or so?

I use eXist-db 3.0.RC1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to wrap your query in an element.

```
<results>{... your query here ...}</results>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping results is the way to go, but if you wish, you can edit /db/apps/eXide/resources/scripts/eXide.min.js, changing "10" in "q=n+10-1" to some other number.

Comment: Actually, wrapping works and I guess it is quite nice practice. However, useful tip!